# Walk through decision tree and capture each node

Tags: python, functional-programming, tree, decision-tree

I'm trying to walk through a Decision Tree one node at a time.

Each node can have 2-3 paths

On the nodes with 3 paths, one of the paths is always an end point, and one is sometimes and end point

We can't move backwards, but can start over

Our available functions are

```
getCurrentNode()        #returns string of current node's path from start (ex. 'A-B-A-A-B')
getCurrentNodePaths()       #returns number of possible paths from this node
startOver()         #puts us back at node 0
takePath(int pathNumber)    #traverse the decision tree down a desired path
```

I've written this pseudo code that should walk through each node recursively, but only for the 'left' most path

```
# Start
def walk(pathNumber):
  takePath(pathNumber)
  next_nodes_paths = getCurrentNodePaths()
  if next_nodes_paths.length > 0:
    walk(0)


startOver()
walk(0)
```

How can I get this to keep track of where it's been, start over, and take a new path

Comment: Are you allowed to add an argument to `walk`?

Comment: Also does `startOver()` reset the value of `getCurrentNode()`?

Comment: @CalebGoodman Yes, please make any changes to `walk`. And yes, `startOver()` resets the value of `getCurrentNode()`

Comment: Can you have a global variable that stores all the checked paths? Like adding each each path from `getCurrentNode()` and than check if it is already in?

Comment: can you use stuff like `networkx` to get this working? it's fairly easy that way,.

Comment: @RaJa Yes, can definitely do that

Comment: @CristinaMorariu We can use any library, as long as it uses the above functions to interface with the tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This creates a model of the decision tree. You can navigate to a certain Node with the select_path method. path is a string like '03231002'. You can walk over the whole tree and apply a function at each point, by using the apply_function method. There is an example for walking the whole tree.

```
def select_path(path):
    startOver()
    for pathNumber in path:
        takePath(int(pathNumber))

class Node:
    def __init__(self,path):
        self.path = path
        self.select()
        self.num_children = getCurrentNodePaths().length
        self.children = [Node(path+str(i)) for i in range(self.num_children)]

    def select(self):
        select_path(self.path)

    def apply_function(self, func, recursive=False):
        self.select()
        func()
        if recursive:
            for child in self.children:
                apply_function(self, func, recursive=True)

root = Node('')

#walk whole tree and apply function function:
#def function:
#    pass
#root.apply_function(function, recursive=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since we cannot move backwards, your approach of (recursive) depth-first search is probably difficult to handle: You can never know if a node is an end node without actually moving there, and once you have arrived, you can only make a new walk to the previous node all the way from the start.

I suggest using a [breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) instead (partly adopted from [this example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/breadth-first-search-or-bfs-for-a-graph/)):

```
def walk(currentNode):
    queue = []
    visited = []
    queue.append(currentNode)
    visited.append(currentNode)
    while queue:
        s = queue.pop(0)
        # go to node from start by following the path
        startOver()
        for p in s:
            takePath(int(p))
        for i in range(getCurrentNodePaths()):
            nextNode = getCurrentNode() + str(i)
            queue.append(nextNode)
            visited.append(nextNode)
        # Use this if you want a list of paths to end points only
        # if getCurrentNodePaths() > 0:
        #     visited.remove(s)
    print(visited)

startOver()
walk(getCurrentNode())
```

This will give you a list of paths to all nodes in your tree in `visited`.

A few notes:

- A node in the `queue` and `visited` lists is assumed to be represented by its path from the start node as a string (e.g. `0`, `101`, `012012`).
- Thus, a node can be reached by just following its sequence of numbers.
- Moreover, the successor nodes can be constructed by
  appending the numbers within `range(getCurrentNodePaths())`.